# Use a Qt library from a C application

Tags: c++, c, qt

Is there a way to write a qt library such that I can then use it (statically linked is fine) in a C application?
My C code is huge, old and will not convert to C++ without an inordinate amount of work. I say this as other similar questions seem to answer "just make your C code a Qt app". That's not an option.
I hope I can write a qt library, and build it in a way that lets it be called from C (something alluded to in QLibrary documentation).

> The symbol must be exported as a C
>   function from the library for
>   resolve() to work. This means that the
>   function must be wrapped in an extern
>   "C" block if the library is compiled
>   with a C++ compiler. On Windows, this
>   also requires the use of a dllexport
>   macro; see resolve() for the details
>   of how this is done.

Can someone confirm/deny that I can do this, and let me know how much "qt" I can put in the library? 
I don't need a GUI but would like to use some of the SQL handling.

Cheers

Mike

Comment: A hint: If you need to export a lot of functions from your C++-based library to C, look at SWIG (http://swig.org/), which generates C++ wrappers for many languages, (C#, Java, Python, but also... C!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put as much Qt in a library as you wish, including full UI capability. The rub is that since you want to access it from C code, you must provide your own access functions and your C functionality will be constrained to whatever level of access you provide.

You can even pass Qt object pointers between C and C++ but you'll need to cast them into something that C can compile -- either `void *` or preferably your own new type definition (such as `C_QString *`). To C code these pointers will be opaque, but they'll still be valid.

Comment: Not only that, but you'll need access functions in the other direction, too. Qt slots are C++ member functions, and you can't use a free function there. But all C functions are free functions.

Comment: I just tried it and now have my (gui!) code embedded in clunky legacy C app. Absolutely brilliant!